# fetch and save attachments from multi part part parameter

Tags: php, imap

usually emails are ok and attachments are saved correctly. 
But some emails have this format and these attachments are not saved. I made correction in code "//peter added   ------------PROBLEM HERE" but now in these affected messages whole message is saved instead of just attachment.

Any idea please?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => ALTERNATIVE
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => boundary
                    [value] => Apple-Mail-A17091CC-3A05-4A36-9F8A-581EB4AB0A36
                )

        )

    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 0
                    [encoding] => 4
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => PLAIN
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [lines] => 33
                    [bytes] => 889
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => charset
                                    [value] => utf-8
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 1
                    [encoding] => 0
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => MIXED
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => boundary
                                    [value] => Apple-Mail-6E5E5872-40F8-49F0-B3AF-18975041DC58
                                )

                        )

                    [parts] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [type] => 0
                                    [encoding] => 4
                                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                                    [subtype] => HTML
                                    [ifdescription] => 0
                                    [ifid] => 0
                                    [lines] => 117
                                    [bytes] => 7333
                                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                                    [ifparameters] => 1
                                    [parameters] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [attribute] => charset
                                                    [value] => utf-8
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [type] => 3
                                    [encoding] => 3
                                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                                    [subtype] => PDF
                                    [ifdescription] => 0
                                    [ifid] => 0
                                    [bytes] => 257790
                                    [ifdisposition] => 1
                                    [disposition] => inline
                                    [ifdparameters] => 1
                                    [dparameters] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [attribute] => filename
                                                    [value] => Exp2EMail.pdf
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [ifparameters] => 1
                                    [parameters] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [attribute] => name
                                                    [value] => Exp2EMail.pdf
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [attribute] => x-apple-part-url
                                                    [value] => 31D06834-B725-4866-973D-6397CB9CEB37
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [type] => 0
                                    [encoding] => 0
                                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                                    [subtype] => HTML
                                    [ifdescription] => 0
                                    [ifid] => 0
                                    [bytes] => 178
                                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                                    [ifparameters] => 1
                                    [parameters] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [attribute] => charset
                                                    [value] => us-ascii
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

my code:

```
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to email: ' . imap_last_error());


/* get all new emails. If set to 'ALL' instead 
 * of 'NEW' retrieves all the emails, but can be 
 * resource intensive, so the following variable, 
 * $max_emails, puts the limit on the number of emails downloaded.
 * 
 */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* useful only if the above search is set to 'ALL' */
$max_emails = 16000000;


/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
if($emails) {

    $count = 1;

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);
    //print_r($emails); die;

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        //print_r($overview); //die;
        //echo $overview[0]["udate"];
        //echo $overview[0]->udate;
        //die;

        /* get mail message */
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);   

        //print_r($message);
        //print_r($structure);



        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }


                //peter added   ------------PROBLEM HERE
                if(isset($structure->parts[$i]->parts)) 
                {
                    //echo 'ano';
                    for($d = 0; $d < count($structure->parts[$i]->parts); $d++) 
                    {                    
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$d]->parameters as $object) 
                        {
                            //print_r($object);
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                                $attachments[$i]['encoding'] = $structure->parts[$i]->parts[$d]->encoding;
                            }
                            //print_r($attachments);
                        }
                    }
                }


                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);
                    //$attachments[$i]['attachment'] = 'aaaa';

                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
//                     /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
//                     elseif($attachments[$i]['encoding'] == 3) 
//                     { 
//                         $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
//                     }
//                     /*4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
//                     elseif($attachments[$i]['encoding'] == 4) 
//                     { 
//                         $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
//                     }
                }
            }
        }


//         print_r($attachments);

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if (mb_substr($filename, 0, 8)=='=?UTF-8?' || mb_substr($filename, 0, 8)=='=?utf-8?') { $filename = imap_utf8($filename); $filename = utf8_decode($filename); }

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
                $date = date('Ymd_His',$overview[0]->udate);
                $fp = fopen($date. ' - '. $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);

//                 print_r($filename);
//                 print_r($attachment);
            }

        }

        if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
    }

} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: I think, but could be wrong, that you are running into an attachment that has an attachment? Is that right?

Comment: I have no idea. Seems like aplle device formated it this way(or forwarded message).

Comment: any idea anyone?

Comment: I would just switch to a recursive function. Pass it your object and have it inspect the object's parameters and/or parts arrays. If they meet the attachment condition, write to disk. If they seem like they are a sub-document, re-pass those parts to the recursive function.